# jQuery : button click event must fire on click, but happens on pageload. how to fix?

Tags: jquery

I have a fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/hhimanshu/SDr3F/2/

- The left pane is already available
- I need that when I click on "search", the input box should show up with focus(an alert for time being)

**Problem**

- When I load the page with left pane setting jQuery fires the event and clicking on "search has no effect"

Please help me understanding what am I doing wrong here

**UPDATE**

- I can see alert, but it fails to focus, here is my latest jQuery

> ```
> // loading search page
> $(function(){
>   $("#search").click(function(){
>       $('#feature').load('templates/search.html');
>       $('#search-input').focus();
>       // alert("hi");
>   });
> });
> ```

and `search.html` is

```
<input id="search-input" type="text" class="input-medium search-query span4 youtube-search-box">
```

How can I focus on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is firing on pageload because that's how you wrote the code

```
$(function(){  // This tells it to run when dom is ready
    alert('hi')    //  Since this is inside the ready function it runs when dom is ready
});
```

What you need is to get the search button element on dom ready and attach a click event handler.  It will now fire whatever code you have inside the .click() function when you click on the element with ID of 'search'

```
$(function(){  
    $('#search').click(function(){  // this tells it to run whenever element with ID "search" is clicked
          alert('hi');
     });
});
```

Here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SDr3F/10/

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#search').click(function(){
    alert('hi')
    //$('#search-input').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the function as part of a click event on the button.  So something like this:

```
$("#search").click(function(){
     alert('hi')
     //$('#search-input').focus();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SDr3F/7/

Answer (score 0):

The `$(document).ready(fn)` means that anything within it executes when the DOM has loaded.

To detect click on the search button, use `$("#search").click(fn)` within the document.ready fn.

Comment: Just realised there is no document.ready, but $(function() {}) is effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your code currently just tells it to run straight away.

```
   $(function(){
     alert('hi')
//$('#search-input').focus();
```

});

You need to add the following:

```
  $("#search").on("click", function(){
     alert('hi')
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a DIV inside your Button.

try this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/SDr3F/9/